# How to convert array of objects to object of array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to convert array of objects to object of array using javascript.

Here is the code

```
const data = [{
  yearMonthKey: "201907",
  dayKey: "15",
  startDate: "2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",
  title: "testProgrma"
},
             {
  yearMonthKey: "201907",
  dayKey: "15",
  startDate: "2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",
  title: "testProgrma"
},
            {
  yearMonthKey: "201907",
  dayKey: "16",
  startDate: "2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",
  title: "testProgrma12313"
},
            {
  yearMonthKey: "201908",
  dayKey: "15",
  startDate: "2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",
  title: "testProgrma"
}]

let programs = {};
```

I want to use **programs** object to make an object out of it like this below.

```
{
  201907: {
    15: [{
      yearMonthKey: "201907",
      dayKey: "15",
      startDate: "2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",
      title: "testProgrma"
    },
        {
      yearMonthKey: "201907",
      dayKey: "15",
      startDate: "2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",
      title: "testProgrma123132"
    }],
    16: [{
        yearMonthKey: "201907",
        dayKey: "16",
        startDate: "2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",
        title: "testProgrma"
      }]
  },
    201908: {
      15: [{
        yearMonthKey: "201908",
        dayKey: "15",
        startDate: "2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",
        title: "testProgrma"
      }]
    }
}
```

I try to solve it using map in array method.

```
data.map(item => {
  programs[item.yearMonthKey] : {
    programs[item.dayKey] : [{

    }]
  }
})
```

but it is bit challenging to sort objects as a value of same **dayKey** key inside of an array and put those inside of same **yearMonthKey**.

Comment: You can't use the function `map` when the desired result is a key-value object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array. Add each `yearMonthKey` to the accumulator. Based on the `yearMonthKey` add a nested `dayKey` key to the `acc[yearMonthKey]` object and default it to an array.

```js
const data=[{yearMonthKey:"201907",dayKey:"15",startDate:"2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",title:"testProgrma"},{yearMonthKey:"201907",dayKey:"15",startDate:"2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",title:"testProgrma"},{yearMonthKey:"201907",dayKey:"16",startDate:"2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",title:"testProgrma12313"},{yearMonthKey:"201908",dayKey:"15",startDate:"2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",title:"testProgrma"}];

const output = data.reduce((acc, o) => {
  if (!acc[o.yearMonthKey]) 
    acc[o.yearMonthKey] = {};
    
  if (!acc[o.yearMonthKey][o.dayKey]) 
    acc[o.yearMonthKey][o.dayKey] = [];
    
  acc[o.yearMonthKey][o.dayKey].push(o);
  
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
  yearMonthKey: "201907",
  dayKey: "15",
  startDate: "2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",
  title: "testProgrma"
},
             {
  yearMonthKey: "201907",
  dayKey: "15",
  startDate: "2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",
  title: "testProgrma"
},
            {
  yearMonthKey: "201907",
  dayKey: "16",
  startDate: "2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",
  title: "testProgrma12313"
},
            {
  yearMonthKey: "201908",
  dayKey: "15",
  startDate: "2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",
  title: "testProgrma"
}]

let programs = {};

data.forEach(function(element) {

    if (typeof programs[element.yearMonthKey] == "undefined") {
        programs[element.yearMonthKey] = {};
    }
    
    if(typeof programs[element.yearMonthKey][element.dayKey] == "undefined") {
        programs[element.yearMonthKey][element.dayKey] = [];
    }
    
    programs[element.yearMonthKey][element.dayKey].push(
        element
    );
});

console.log(programs);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data=[{yearMonthKey:"201907",dayKey:"15",startDate:"2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",title:"testProgrma"},{yearMonthKey:"201907",dayKey:"15",startDate:"2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",title:"testProgrma"},{yearMonthKey:"201907",dayKey:"16",startDate:"2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",title:"testProgrma12313"},{yearMonthKey:"201908",dayKey:"15",startDate:"2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",title:"testProgrma"}];

const dist_yearMonthKeys = [...new Set(data.map(d => d.yearMonthKey))];

let program = {};
for (let ymk of dist_yearMonthKeys) {
    const ymk_num = parseInt(ymk); // error-prone, be careful with your source data
    program[ymk_num] = {};
    const dist_dayKeys = [...new Set(data.filter(d => d.yearMonthKey === ymk).map(d => d.dayKey))];
    for (let dk of dist_dayKeys) {
        const dk_num = parseInt(dk); // error-prone
        program[ymk_num][dk_num] = data.filter(d => d.dayKey === dk && d.yearMonthKey === ymk);
    }
}

console.log(program);
```

This gives numeric keys, like you requested.

Comment: There is no point in doing `parseInt(ymk)`. Keys of an object are either a string or a Symbol. When you add `program[ymk_num]` it will be converted to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Universal function for grouping with any keys

```
function group() {
   const args = Array.from(arguments)
   const data = args.shift()

   const result = {}
   data.forEach(elem => {
      let level = result
      args.forEach((groupProp, ind) => {
         const groupValue = elem[groupProp]
         if (groupValue in level) {
            level = level[groupValue]
         } else {
            level = level[groupValue] = ind === args.length - 1 ? [] : {}
         }
      })
      level.push(elem)
   })

   return result   
}

const data = [{
  yearMonthKey: "201907",
  dayKey: "15",
  startDate: "2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",
  title: "testProgrma"
},
             {
  yearMonthKey: "201907",
  dayKey: "15",
  startDate: "2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",
  title: "testProgrma"
},
            {
  yearMonthKey: "201907",
  dayKey: "16",
  startDate: "2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",
  title: "testProgrma12313"
},
            {
  yearMonthKey: "201908",
  dayKey: "15",
  startDate: "2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",
  title: "testProgrma"
}]

const result = group(data, 'yearMonthKey', 'dayKey')
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

try destructuring the list and putting it back together in the format you want

```
const data = [{
  yearMonthKey: "201907",
  dayKey: "15",
  startDate: "2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",
  title: "testProgrma"
},
             {
  yearMonthKey: "201907",
  dayKey: "15",
  startDate: "2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",
  title: "testProgrma"
},
            {
  yearMonthKey: "201907",
  dayKey: "16",
  startDate: "2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",
  title: "testProgrma12313"
},
            {
  yearMonthKey: "201908",
  dayKey: "15",
  startDate: "2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",
  title: "testProgrma"
}]

const [1,2,3,4] = data
```

so now when you call variable 1 you would get

```
{
  yearMonthKey: "201907",
  dayKey: "15",
  startDate: "2019-07-15 00:00:00+0900",
  title: "testProgrma"
}
```

Now you can handle each object individually instead of in a list. As such you can basically do whatever you want with the objects