# how to change json data by javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a Json data

```
   var orign = {
            users: [
                { name: "name1", id: "aaa1", classify: "depth1" },
                { name: "name2", id: "aaa2", classify: "depth1" },
                { name: "name3", id: "aaa3", classify: "depth2" },
            ]
        }
```

I want to change json data
like this

```
        var result = {
            "depth1" : [
                { name: "name1", id: "aaa1"},
                { name: "name2", id: "aaa2"},
            ],
            "depth2" : [
                { name: "name3", id: "aaa3"},
            ],
           
        }
```

how can I change this by Javascript?

Comment: Do you currently have any code, which you could provide?

Comment: Please be aware that `var orign = { ... }` is not JSON, it is a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce),

```js
origin = {
            users: [
                { name: "name1", id: "aaa1", classify: "depth1" },
                { name: "name2", id: "aaa2", classify: "depth1" },
                { name: "name3", id: "aaa3", classify: "depth2" },
            ]
        }

res = origin.users.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  const {classify, ...rest} = curr;
  if(prev.hasOwnProperty(classify)) {
    prev[classify].push(rest);
  } else {
    prev[classify] = [rest];
  }
  return prev;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite similar question I posted a year ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59322599/how-to-convert-array-of-objects-to-object-of-array-in-javascript)

Hope my answer could help

```js
var origin = {
  users: [
      { name: "name1", id: "aaa1", classify: "depth1" },
      { name: "name2", id: "aaa2", classify: "depth1" },
      { name: "name3", id: "aaa3", classify: "depth2" },
  ]
};

const reducer = (acc, item) => {
  if (!acc[item.classify]) {
    acc[item.classify] = [];    
  } 
  acc[item.classify].push({name: item.name, id: item.id})
  
  return acc
}

const result = origin.users.reduce(reducer, {});

console.log(result)
```